# Unknown column in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SET @CompanyId = "2030";

SELECT DISTINCT (NAME) 
FROM i18ninterviewmodel 
WHERE LocaleId='1' 
AND InterviewModelId IN (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM interviewmodel 
    WHERE TYPE IN ('ABC','123') 
    AND Id IN (
        SELECT InterviewModelId 
        FROM companyinterview 
        WHERE STATUS='ACTV' 
        AND CompanyId=@CompanyId
    )
)
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

I would like to rewrite this by using JOINS, but am having issues. When I use the below, I keep getting an error that says

> Unknown column 'companyinterview.Status' in 'where clause'

```
SET @CompanyId = "2030";

SELECT i18ninterviewmodel.Name 
FROM i18ninterviewmodel
JOIN i18ninterviewmodel i18 
    ON interviewmodel.Id = i18.InterviewModelId
JOIN interviewmodel 
    ON companyinterview.InterviewModelId = interviewmodel.Id
WHERE i18ninterviewmodel.LocaleId='1' 
AND companyinterview.Status='ACTV' 
AND companyinterview.CompanyId=@CompanyId 
AND interviewmodel.type IN ('ABC','123') 
ORDER BY i18ninterviewmodel.Name ASC;
```

I don't have a lot of experience with MySQL, so I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: You don't seem to join `companyinterview` at all. Are you sure, after the second `JOIN` you don't want to write `companyinterview` there instead of joining `interviewmodel` again?

Comment: yeah,,,you could at best use companyinterview in where

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you join the table `companyinterview` at any point.

I guess you wanted to write this:

```
SET @CompanyId = "2030";
SELECT i18ninterviewmodel.Name FROM i18ninterviewmodel
JOIN i18ninterviewmodel i18 ON interviewmodel.Id = i18.InterviewModelId
JOIN companyinterview ON companyinterview.InterviewModelId = interviewmodel.Id
WHERE i18ninterviewmodel.LocaleId='1' AND companyinterview.Status='ACTV' AND companyinterview.CompanyId=@CompanyId AND interviewmodel.type IN ('ABC','123') ORDER BY i18ninterviewmodel.Name AS
```

Answer (score 0):

remove from join  , and add to where

```
   SET @CompanyId = "2030";
        SELECT i18ninterviewmodel.Name FROM i18ninterviewmodel
        JOIN i18ninterviewmodel i18 ON interviewmodel.Id = i18.InterviewModelId
        JOIN interviewmodel ON interviewmodel.Id
        WHERE i18ninterviewmodel.LocaleId='1' AND companyinterview.Status='ACTV' AND companyinterview.CompanyId=@CompanyId
AND interviewmodel.type IN ('ABC','123') 
AND  companyinterview.InterviewModelId =i18.InterviewModelId
ORDER BY i18ninterviewmodel.Name ASC
```